# Group a child class on transient parent attributes for a custom FungibleState schema

Tags: hibernate, kotlin, corda

In Corda V3, we are extending `FungibleState` as described in the [API Vault Query](https://docs.corda.net/api-vault-query.html) documentation:

```
object CustomSchemaV1 : MappedSchema(schemaFamily = CustomSchema.javaClass, version = 1, mappedTypes = listOf(PersistentCustomState::class.java))
{
@Entity
@Table(name = "custom_states", indexes = arrayOf(Index(name = "custom_field_idx", columnList = "custom_field")))
class PersistentCustomState(

/** Custom attributes */
@Column(name = "custom_field")
var customField: String? = null,

/** FungibleState parent attributes */
@Transient
val _participants: Set<AbstractParty>,
@Transient
val _owner: AbstractParty,
@Transient
val _quantity: Long,
@Transient
val _issuerParty: AbstractParty,
@Transient
val _issuerRef: OpaqueBytes
) : CommonSchemaV1.FungibleState(_participants?.toMutableSet(), _owner, _quantity, _issuerParty, _issuerRef.bytes)}
```

Using this kind of schema, how can we sum the `_quantity` parent field, groupd by `custom_field`?

Looking at the samples, we were trying to use `QueryCriteria`:

```
val sum = builder {
    CustomSchemaV1.PersistentCustomState::_quantity.sum(
        groupByColumns = listOf(
            CustomSchemaV1.PersistentCustomState::customField
        ),
        orderBy = Sort.Direction.ASC
    )
}
return QueryCriteria.VaultCustomQueryCriteria(sum)
```

But this throws an error: `Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [_quantity] on this ManagedType [net.corda.core.schemas.PersistentState]`

We were able to workaround removing the `@Transient` annotation which persists the `quantity` on the child class as well, but this leads to storing duplicate values in the database.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered trying something like:

```
object CustomSchemaV1 : MappedSchema(schemaFamily = CustomSchema.javaClass, version = 1, mappedTypes = listOf(PersistentCustomState::class.java))
{
@Entity
@Table(name = "custom_states", indexes = arrayOf(Index(name = "custom_field_idx", columnList = "custom_field")))
class PersistentCustomState(

/** Custom attributes */
@Column(name = "custom_field")
var customField: String? = null,

/** FungibleState parent attributes */
participants: MutableSet<AbstractParty>?,
owner: AbstractParty,
quantity: Long,
issuerParty: AbstractParty,
issuerRef: OpaqueBytes
) : CommonSchemaV1.FungibleState(participants, owner, quantity, issuerParty, issuerRef.bytes)}
```

and then using the inherited `quantity` column? `CommonSchemaV1.FungibleState` is a `MappedSuperclass`, so its columns will be mapped into the child entity.

Comment: Tried that approach but now I'm getting errors on the CommonSchemaV1: `Please register the entity 'net.corda.core.schemas.CommonSchemaV1'`

Which is odd since this obviously is not a custom schema. Same error when running the `NodeDriver` or using the cordapp jars.

Comment: Hmm, this is interesting. This looks like it might be a bug in Corda, and we'll need to dig a bit deeper here. We have managed to reproduce this problem using `SampleCashSchemaV2` from the `finance` module's own unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug which is being tracked here: https://r3-cev.atlassian.net/browse/CORDA-1338.